# kubernetes node scaling based on number of pods per node

Tags: kubernetes

We can scale the nodes in a Kubernetes cluster based on CPU or Memory, can we autoscale the nodes based on the pod pressure (number of pods per node)?
In many of my cases, the CPU and Memory is not the most demanded resources, but number of pods per node is usually under pressure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Kubernetes there is no option to offer an auto scaling mechanism based on the number of pods per node. Instead you can use [Cluster Autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler). Cluster Autoscaler doesn't depend on load metrics. Instead, it's based on scheduling simulation and declared Pod requests.  This can create new nodes when there is a demand for more pods and scale down nodes when there are no more pods to schedule on them, effectively balancing the number of pods per node.  For more information on cluster autoscaling refer to this [Gitlink](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler) and [blog](https://learnk8s.io/kubernetes-autoscaling-strategies) by Daniele Polencic

If in case you are looking for this in GKE then refer to the [official doc- GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler) and [Cluster Autoscaler](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/best-practices-for-running-cost-effective-kubernetes-applications-on-gke#cluster_autoscaler)

If you need this feature to implement this in future, you can also raise an issue request [here](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

**EDIT :**

@xsqian : Based on your comments, you are using AWS `m5.2xlarge`  instances. The maximum number of pods per EKS instance are actually listed in this  [eni-max-pods git link](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-eks-ami/blob/master/files/eni-max-pods.txt)

The [formula](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-eks-ami/blob/master/files/eni-max-pods.txt) for defining the maximum number of pods per instance is as follows:

> N * (M-1) + 2
>
> Where:
>
> - N is the number of Elastic Network Interfaces (ENI) of the instance type
> - M is the number of IP addresses of a single ENI
>
> Values for `N` and `M` for each instance type in this [Elastic network
> interface doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html#AvailableIpPerEN)

Based on this as you are using `m5.2xlarge` the pod limit is 58 only and as you are using two nodes then the pod limit is 116 only. This is a soft limit only you can't add anymore pods beyond the 116, if you try to add then this will move into a pending state.

But It is advised that as of August 2021 it's now possible to increase the max pods on a node using the latest AWS CNI plugin as described in this [amazon-vpc-cni-increases-pods-per-node-limits](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/amazon-vpc-cni-increases-pods-per-node-limits/) and refer to this [EKS user guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/cni-increase-ip-addresses.html).

Comment: Hi Hemanth, thank you for the information. The blog by Daniele is a good read on the topic. However, I am still wondering if there is a feature in the Cluster Autoscaler that can scale up a node based on the number of pods in disregard of the CPU and Memory resource. For example, suppose I have 2 nodes running now, have abundant  CUP and Memory resource for schedule more pods, however, the number of pods is over the limit of total 116 already (58 each AWS m5.2xlarge), is this number of pod limit a soft limit or a hard limit?

Comment: That means can I schedule another pod unto the 2 existing nodes? Or is there a way to trigger the Cluster Autoscaler to scale up an additional node based on the fact that the the total demand pod number is over the limit os 116?

Comment: @xsqian :based on your comments, i have edited the answer in edit section to make you clear understanding.